# jquery и добавление/удаление строк в таблице

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, матрицы

Есть таблицы, имеющие размерность от 2 до 10, есть кнопки, которые добавтяют/удаляют в таблицах строки/столбцы

[image: таблицы]

[image: кнопки]

1) С добавлением и удалением проблем не возникло, но не получилось сделать ограничения, т.е. изначально кнопки удалить неактивны, после добавления строк и столбцов активируются, тоже самое и с добавлением, когда строк или столбцов 10, кнопки "добавить" становятся неактивными при уменьшении вновь активны

```
$('.add_row').click(function(){
    if ($("#amatrix").prop("checked")){
        $('#Atable tr:last').clone().appendTo('#Atable tbody'); 
    }else if($("#bmatrix").prop("checked")) {
        $('#Btable tr:last').clone().appendTo('#Btable tbody'); 
    }
});

if ($('#Atable tr').length > 2) {
    $('.del_row').removeAttr("disabled").click(function(){
        if ($("#amatrix").prop("checked")){
            $('#Atable tr:last').remove();  
        }else if($("#bmatrix").prop("checked")) {
            $('#Btable tr:last').remove();  
        }
    });
} else {
    $('.del_row').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

2) Вторая проблема в том, что при редактировании полей таблиц блок с кнопками меняет цвет, но это работает только для уже существующих полей, при редактировании добавленных ничего не происходит. Как можно отследить и добавляющиеся элементы? И тоже с placeholder, подскажите как заполять верными значениями новые поля?

```
$('.elem_matrix').bind("change input", function() {
    $('.left_side').css('background', '#5199db');
}).focusout(function(){
    $('.left_side').css('background', '#bcbcbc');
});
```

Comment: хтмл не помешал бы

Comment: @Jean-Claude разметка тут https://jsfiddle.net/jzk4cx43/

Comment: а че джабаскрипт туда трудно было вставить?